# How to view dictionary having foreign key to itself at template level in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a model.py like this:

```
class EventTypeCategory(models.Model):

      name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Name")
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="User")
      Message_slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, verbose_name="Message")
      sub_categories = models.ForeignKey('self', verbose_name="Self-Categories", null =True, blank = True)
```

**Whereas sub_categories field are foreign key to itself**

I have a view.py like this:

```
@login_required
def eventcateg_detail(request):
    ca = EventTypeCategory.objects.values()
    return render_to_response('events/categ.html',{
        'obj': ca,
        })
```

whereas ca returns a dictionary as follow:

```
[{'Message_slug': u'ngcg', 'sub_categories_id': 124L, 'user_id': 1L, 'id': 146L, 'name': u'ngcg'}, {'Message_slug': u'lkn', 'sub_categories_id': 146L, 'user_id': 1L, 'id': 149L, 'name': u'lkn '}]
```

I want to print values of "Sub-categories ,Message" and "name" from each dictionary content at categ.html. Whereas sub_categories are returning "id" ( foreign key to pointing itself). I am newbie at Django and also had look similar questions but it didn't work for me :(

data should be print like this at categ.html:

```
Message:    Name:    Sub-categories:
ngcg        ngcg      (values which refer to foriegn key)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, We use QuerySet.all(), which return model-instance objects, instead of QuerySet.values().

> If you have a field called foo that is a ForeignKey, the default
>   values() call will return a dictionary key called foo_id, since this
>   is the name of the hidden model attribute that stores the actual value
>   (the foo attribute refers to the related model).

Check the doc:
[django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values).

```
@login_required
def eventcateg_detail(request):
    ca = EventTypeCategory.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('events/categ.html',{
        'objs': ca,
        })
```

Now, the obj is a EventTypeCategory instance.

```
{% for obj in objs %}
    {{obj.Message_slug}}, {{obj.name}}, {{obj.sub_categories.name}}
    ngcg,                 ngcg,         (name of instance which refer to foriegn key)
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Just use the 'objs' as a List.

Comment: Also, according to the doc, values() ignores select_related and causes multiple query instead of join.